# How to set two loops in React JS

Tags: javascript, loops, reactjs

I'm getting an array that contains another array inside of it. It is a json. I'm trying to do two loops, but without success.

```
{this.state.listOfAlarms && this.state.listOfAlarms.map((alarms) =>
    {alarms.report && alarms.report.forEach((alarm) =>
        <ReportAlarmRow alarm={alarms} alarmType={alarm}/>
    )}
)}
```

I had tried to start with forEach and after do the .maps. Failed again.

Comment: forEach returns nothing. so you will end up with an array full of undefineds.

Comment: Try to remove curly braces after first `=>`

Comment: It should be ".map" not ".maps"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability, you should do those loops before the `return` statement.

In addition, you need to add a `key` property to your `<ReportAlarmRow>` component.

> A "key" is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.
>
> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

[Lists and Keys - React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

I set a key with `key={alarm[i].id}` but I don't know what attributes are in your `alarm` object.
Please, **use a unique *int* value** !

> Keys Must Only Be Unique Among Siblings

Try like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  // State
  this.state = {
    listOfAlarms: []
  }
}

render() {
  const reports = this.state.listOfAlarms.map((alarms) => {
    if (alarms.report) {
      return alarms.report.map((alarm) => 
        <ReportAlarmRow alarm={alarms} alarmType={alarm} key={alarm.id} />
      );
    }
  });

  return {
    <div>
      { reports.length ? reports : null }
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const something = [
      [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      [
        4,
        5,
        6
      ]
    ]
    const JSXElem = something.map((elem) => {
      elem.map((nestedElem) => {
        // <Render Method>
      })
    })
    return <div>{JSXElem}</div>;
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried this way, but it it returns that .map is not a function. :(

Comment: You should replace `<Render Method>` with your own render method. And also I haven't tried running this but should give you the picture. Try adding proper return statements and debug, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this

```
render(){
    let a = [ [1,2],[3,5],[7,8]];
    return(
       <div>
        {(()=>{
          let items = [];
          if(a){
            a.forEach((index,value)=>{
               value.forEach((i,item)=>{
                 items.push(<div key={ `${index}_${i}`}>item</div>)
               })
            })
          }
          return items;
        })()}
       </div>
     )
}
```